# Deploying Jersey based Restful webservice in Weblogic 12c

Tags: java, rest, jax-rs, weblogic12c, weblog

I have developed a very small restful Web Service in eclipse using the "jersey" archetype.I was also successful in deploying that in tomcat. However, I am unable to deploy that in weblogic 12c. This is what I have tried so far:

1. created a shared library containing the jersey libraries as I have
   seen in one of the post. This is my pom.xml which generates the
   shared library containing the required manifest file:

> Blockquote

```
    <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>jersey-shared-lib</groupId>
  <artifactId>jersey-shared-lib</artifactId>
  <version>2.21</version>

  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-client</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jettison</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-multipart</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
        <dependency>
      <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
      <artifactId>jersey-media-sse</artifactId>
      <version>${project.version}</version>
    </dependency>
     <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${project.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.1.1</version>
        <configuration>
          <packagingExcludes>WEB-INF/classes</packagingExcludes>
          <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
          <archive>
            <manifestEntries>
              <Specification-Title>Weblogic JAX-RS 2.0</Specification-Title>
              <Specification-Version>2.0</Specification-Version>
              <Implementation-Title>Weblogic JAX-RS 2.0 Reference Implementation</Implementation-Title>
              <Implementation-Version>${project.version}</Implementation-Version>
              <Extension-Name>jax-rs</Extension-Name>
            </manifestEntries>
          </archive>
              <webResources> 
            <resource>
              <filtering>true</filtering>
              <directory>src/main/webapp</directory>
              <includes>
                <include>WEB-INF/weblogic.xml</include>
              </includes>
            </resource>
          </webResources>
            </configuration>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
    </project>
```

2. Deployed the war in weblogic server as a "library"
3. Added a
   weblogic.xml under WEB-INF folder in my webservice application with
   the following entry:
       
       http://xmlns.oracle.com/weblogic/weblogic-web-app/1.7/weblogic-web-app.xsd">

   ```
       <wls:library-ref>
           <wls:library-name>jax-rs</wls:library-name>
           <wls:specification-version>2.0</wls:specification-version>
           <wls:implementation-version>2.21</wls:implementation-version>
            <exact-match>false</exact-match>
       </wls:library-ref>
   ```
4. Generated the web-service war file using the below pom.xml

> ```
>       <project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
>       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
>       xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
>   <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
>   <groupId>com.cts</groupId>
>   <artifactId>WLRest</artifactId>
>   <packaging>war</packaging>
>   <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
>   <name>WLRest</name>
>   <build>
>       <finalName>WLRest</finalName>
>       <plugins>
>           <plugin>
>               <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
>               <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
>               <version>2.5.1</version>
>               <inherited>true</inherited>
>               <configuration>
>                   <source>1.7</source>
>                   <target>1.7</target>
>               </configuration>
>           </plugin>
>       </plugins>
>   </build>
>
>   <dependencyManagement>
>       <dependencies>
>           <dependency>
>               <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
>               <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
>               <version>${jersey.version}</version>
>               <type>pom</type>
>               <scope>provided</scope>
>           </dependency>
>       </dependencies>
>   </dependencyManagement>
>
>   <dependencies>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId>
>           <version>${jersey.version}</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
>           <artifactId>jersey-media-moxy</artifactId>
>           <version>${jersey.version}</version>
>           <scope>provided</scope>
>       </dependency>
>       <dependency>
>           <groupId>com.wordnik</groupId>
>           <artifactId>swagger-core_2.10</artifactId>
>           <version>1.3.11</version>
>           <exclusions>
>               <exclusion>
>                   <groupId>javax.ws.rs</groupId>
>                   <artifactId>jsr311-api</artifactId>
>               </exclusion>
>           </exclusions>
>       </dependency>
>   </dependencies>
>   <properties>
>       <jersey.version>2.21</jersey.version>
>       <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
>   </properties>
> </project>
> ```

And with the below we.xml entries:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container,
     see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.cts.WLRest</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Now, when I am trying to deploy the the war in weblogic, it is throwing the following exception:

```
An error occurred during activation of changes, please see the log for details.
[HTTP:101216]Servlet: "Jersey Web Application" failed to preload on startup in Web application: "WLRest.war". java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map; at org.glassfish.jersey.server.ApplicationHandler.<init>(ApplicationHandler.java:329) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.WebComponent.<init>(WebComponent.java:390) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:170) at org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer.init(ServletContainer.java:362) at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:240) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:299) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletInitAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:250) at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321) at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120) at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.initServletInstance(StubSecurityHelper.java:94) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.createServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:82) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.createOneInstance(StubLifecycleHelper.java:74) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:60) at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubLifecycleHelper.<init>(StubLifecycleHelper.java:34) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.initStubLifecycleHelper(ServletStubImpl.java:624) at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.prepareServlet(ServletStubImpl.java:565) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadServlet(WebAppServletContext.java:1874) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.loadServletsOnStartup(WebAppServletContext.java:1848) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.preloadResources(WebAppServletContext.java:1738) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.start(WebAppServletContext.java:2740) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.startContexts(WebAppModule.java:1704) at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppModule.start(WebAppModule.java:781) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ScopedModuleDriver.start(ScopedModuleDriver.java:212) at weblogic.application.internal.ExtensibleModuleWrapper.start(ExtensibleModuleWrapper.java:111) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleListenerInvoker.start(ModuleListenerInvoker.java:124) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:213) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver$3.next(ModuleStateDriver.java:208) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.ModuleStateDriver.start(ModuleStateDriver.java:70) at weblogic.application.internal.flow.StartModulesFlow.activate(StartModulesFlow.java:24) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment$2.next(BaseDeployment.java:729) at weblogic.application.utils.StateMachineDriver.nextState(StateMachineDriver.java:35) at weblogic.application.internal.BaseDeployment.activate(BaseDeployment.java:258) at weblogic.application.internal.SingleModuleDeployment.activate(SingleModuleDeployment.java:48) at weblogic.application.internal.DeploymentStateChecker.activate(DeploymentStateChecker.java:165) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.AppContainerInvoker.activate(AppContainerInvoker.java:79) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.activate(AbstractOperation.java:582) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.activateDeployment(ActivateOperation.java:148) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.ActivateOperation.doCommit(ActivateOperation.java:114) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.operations.AbstractOperation.commit(AbstractOperation.java:335) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleDeploymentCommit(DeploymentManager.java:844) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.activateDeploymentList(DeploymentManager.java:1253) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentManager.handleCommit(DeploymentManager.java:440) at weblogic.deploy.internal.targetserver.DeploymentServiceDispatcher.commit(DeploymentServiceDispatcher.java:163) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.doCommitCallback(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:195) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.access$100(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:13) at weblogic.deploy.service.internal.targetserver.DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer$2.run(DeploymentReceiverCallbackDeliverer.java:68) at weblogic.work.SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl$WorkAdapterImpl.run(SelfTuningWorkManagerImpl.java:545) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:256) at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:221) 
javax.ws.rs.core.Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;
```

I have also used maven dependency tree and Jshades to confirm there is no conflict between different version of jars. Any help or pointer on this will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This is caused by a JAX-RS 1.x API jar on the classpath. I see you excluded the jsr311 so I am not sure what would be causing it. But that's the reason for the error

Answer (score 1):

This is beacause Weblogic puts its own jars for some libraries. In this case it's an older version of jax-rs. 
You can see that this method is new to JAX-RS 2:

[Application javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/ws/rs/core/Application.html#getProperties--)

In order to enforce your packages, you need to configure prefer application packages in WLS:

[prefer-application-packages](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e21049/weblogic_xml.htm#WBAPP660)

You also need to understand this:

[Class loading in WLS](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E24329_01/web.1211/e24368/classloading.htm#WLPRG282)